# Lodash deep object testing using has()

Tags: lodash

For example, we have this kind of data

```
user = {
   name : 'Scott',
   info : {
      age : 25,
      addr1 : 'A',
      addr2 : 'B',
      zipCode : 60000
   }
}
```

I'd like to test each info. To me, the code below looks very elementary

```
if (_.has(usr, 'info.age') && _.has(usr, 'info.addr1') && _.has(usr, 'info.addr2') && _.has(usr, 'info.zipCode')) {
    // do your stuff since all criteria were met
}
```

That's a lot of code. What's the best way to refactor it?

Comment: You could create function and give all object parameters in as an array. something like _.hasArray(object, arrayOfDotMappedProperties)

Comment: Tho lodash already supports this functionality: _.has(object, ['a', 'b', 'c']);

Comment: @LauriOrgla I tried it but I'm getting a false once I add the second property.

Comment: @LauriOrgla, that example you wrote is for nested objects and not single level. I saw it in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of props you want to check, and run them through [_.every()](https://lodash.com/docs#every):

```
var props = ['age', 'addr1', 'addr2', 'zipCode'];

if(typeof user === "object" && _.every(props, function(prop) { return _.has(user.info, prop);  })) {
    console.log('whatever you want to do');
}
```

If you need to check more sub props in the object, you can do it like this:

```
user = {
   name : 'Scott',
   moreInfo: { // another sub section of props
      gender: 'm'
   },
   info : {
      age : 25,
      addr1 : 'A',
      addr2 : 'B',
      zipCode : 60000
   }
}

var props = ['info.age', 'info.addr1', 'info.addr2', 'info.zipCode', 'moreInfo.gender'];

if(_.every(props, function(prop) { return _.has(user, prop);  })) {
    console.log('whatever you want to do');
}
```

Comment: This will throw if user is null, the original code by OP will not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [difference()](https://lodash.com/docs#difference) and [keys()](https://lodash.com/docs#keys) for this:

```
var props = [ 'age', 'addr1', 'addr2', 'zipCode' ];

if (!_.difference(props, _.keys(user.info)).length) {
    // Has required properties...
}
```